# Oracle says missing, misspelled or misplaced FROM

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net

I'm testing for the first time my connection with Oracle. Connection by itself seems to work. However...

> SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM my_core.my_table

Is the sentence I use

and on

> retVal = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Throws

**ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected**

```
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode,
OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src
, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, Oracle
Connection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx
, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Bool
ean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   in thiscs.Main() en C:\app\testuser\product\11.2.0\my\sample\thiscs.cs:line 44
```

Here's the code:

```
// C#

using System;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Transactions;

class thiscs
{
  static void Main()
  {
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    string providerName = "Oracle.DataAccess.Client";
    #region constr
    string constr =
       @"User Id=mytestuser;Password=mytestpass;Data Source=10.210.10.81:1521/my.svc.net;";

    #endregion

    // Get the provider factory.
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

    try
    {
      // Open a connection to the DB.
      DbConnection conn1 = factory.CreateConnection();
      conn1.ConnectionString = constr;
      conn1.Open();

      // Create a command to execute the sql statement.
      DbCommand cmd1 = factory.CreateCommand();
      cmd1.Connection = conn1;
      cmd1.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM my_core.my_table";
      
      // Execute the SQL statement to Select one rowfield in DB.
      retVal = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
      Console.WriteLine("Field to be showed by cmd1: {0}", retVal);

      // close and dispose the connection
      conn1.Close();
      conn1.Dispose();
      cmd1.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried also

> SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM my_core.my_table
>
> SELECT 'hey apple, apple, hey'

Both with the same result: **ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected**

Any Ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TOP** is not a keyword in the Oracle vocabulary, at least not in the context you want it to be.

**TOP** is the syntax used by Microsoft SQL Server.

To replicate this, rewrite your SQL to this:

```
SELECT ID FROM my_core.my_table WHERE rownum <= 1
```

In other words, transform:

```
this: SELECT TOP N .... WHERE ...
                 |
                 +------------------------------+
                                                v
to:   SELECT       .... WHERE ... AND rownum <= N
```

Also see here:

- [Oracle/PLSQL: Retrieve Top N records from a query](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/top_records.php)

**Also** note that the query, as presented in your example is rather nonsensical. Given time, index usage, table organization, etc. will change, which means that that unless you specify an ordering, which specific ID you will retrieve might/will change.

Comment: Oh, I see, It seems that being an SQL-T dev made me a somewhat Microsoft language adept... let me try that.

Comment: It has thrown an ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected ROWID got NUMBER

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be **rownum**